# std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > in min_heap function

Tags: c++, priority-queue

In the line below vector is used in the parameter list

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> >
```

**Questions:**

1. what is the purpose of using vector?
2. is vector utilized making the priority queue?
3. can we use anything else other than vector?

Comment: Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::vector` is the underlying container used to implement the priority queue.

You can use any container type, given the following constrains (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> The container must satisfy the requirements of SequenceContainer, and
>   its iterators must satisfy the requirements of RandomAccessIterator.
>
> Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual
>   semantics:
>
> front()
>
> push_back()
>
> pop_back()
>
> The standard containers std::vector and std::deque satisfy these requirements.